# Hibernate could not resolve property of the Embedded class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Embeddable class, which is embedded in an entity.

```
@Embeddable
public class RawObservation{
 @NotNull
    @Column(name="RAW_CODE")
    private String rawCode;
```

//getters,setters
    }

```
@Entity
    public class TankObservation{
    @Embedded
        private RawObservation rawObservation;
    }
```

When I try to make a GET query with "rawCode" parameter;

Hiberanate throws following exception[1];

How can I overcome this?

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: rawCode of: com.abc.TankObservation
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1770)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:510)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.findColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:525)
    at org.hibernate.criterion.SimpleExpression.toSqlString(SimpleExpression.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getWhereCondition(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1760)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
    at com.cdi.crud.infra.Crud.list(Crud.java:437)
    at com.cdi.crud.infra.CrudService.paginate(CrudService.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
```

**Edit :**

```
public Criteria configPagination(Filter<TankObservation> filter) {
  if (filter.getEntity() != null) {


        if(filter.getEntity().getRawObservation().getRawCode() != null){
            crud().eq("rawCode", filter.getEntity().getRawObservation().getRawCode());
        }

        if(filter.getEntity().getRawObservation().getProductCode() != null){
            crud().eq("productCode", filter.getEntity().getRawObservation().getProductCode());
        }


}

  return crud().getCriteria();
}
```

Comment: have you annotated class `TankObservation` as `Entity`?

Comment: @Saravana Yes, it is an Entity.

Comment: could you post the Criteria code or sql ?

Comment: @Saravana it is bit big classes..I posted a small code block of getting Criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not property `rawCode` in the `TankObservation`. Please, use 
`rawObservation.rawCode` to refer `rawCode` from `TankObservation`.

Comment: Im doing like that ? if(filter.getEntity().getRawObservation().getRawCode() != null){
            crud().eq("rawCode", filter.getEntity().getRawObservation().getRawCode());
        }

Comment: @Ratha `crud().eq("rawObservation.rawCode", ...`

Comment: Thanks, exception gone.

Comment: @v.ladynev I tried HQL with just `rawCode` it worked

Comment: @Saravana Probably, you use SQL or other mapping. :)